# Is there a way to force Delphi to leave unused code in the executable?

Tags: delphi

The Delphi Linker strips out any functions that aren't actually used, thus reducing the executable size.

Is there any way to stop the Delphi Linker doing this? e.g. a compiler switch?

To those wondering "why?"...

I am trying to use the [delphi-code-coverage tool](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage/), but it only reports on code that is actually compiled into the executable. Which makes it not very useful. If I could get Delphi to include all code, I'm hoping I could then get some useful code coverage statistics.

I should mention that I have DUnit tests in a separate project to my application. So even though the code is "unused" in the DUnit project, it *is* used in the actual application.

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage/issues/detail?id=19) for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code-coverage tool is measuring the wrong thing. It works off the map file instead of the source code, so it will only report on *live* code instead of on *all* code in a project. The linker already filters out the *dead* code, and in a blank unit-test project, *all* code is dead code. There is no way to tell Delphi to include dead code in an EXE.

Run the code-coverage tool on your application to get a list of functions that needs testing. Then, write code in your unit-test project that mentions all those functions. (It doesn't have to *call* everything yet, and it certainly doesn't have to *test* it all. We're just making sure it's linked to the unit-test project.) Now the coverage tool can get an accurate measurement of what's been executed and what hasn't.

Comment: How do I *mention* a function but not *call* it?

Comment: Take its address. For example, `AssertEquals(nil, @Foo)`. That not only ensures that `Foo` is linked to your program, but also gives you a failing unit test, reminding you that you're not finished testing yet.